# NextJs Mongoose multiple models not working

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, next.js, mongoose-schema

nextjs data fetching only from first Model when added second model nothing gonna happened

My first Model

```
import {Schema, model,models} from 'mongoose'; 
const est = new Schema({
    name:{
        type:String
    },
    body:{
        type:String
    } 
});
const blogs= models.blogs || model('blogs', est); 
export default blogs;
```

second model

```
import {Schema, model,models} from 'mongoose'; 
const est = new Schema({
    name:{
        type:String
    },
    body:{
        type:String
    } 
});
const mocktest= models.mocktest || model('mocktest', est); 
export default mocktest;
```

Imported Like this

```
import blogs from '../../models/test';
import mocktest from '../../models/mtest';
```

First one working perfect but second model not works
can any help to fix this

Answer (score 0):

just adding collection name to schema will works

example

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
   // collection: Student
    "Id" : Number,
    "Name" : String,
    "Subject" : String,
    "Marks" : Number

  }, {collection: 'Student'});
```